# MsDeploy: 2 webapplications in one solution

Tags: c#, msdeploy

Here is my current setup: I have 1 solution (sln file) which holds 2 c# web applications inside one folder.
When I publish solution with parameter `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True` - it is delivered correctly.
But, such an approach is not as good as it seems - it leaves deleted from solution files on server, and, in worst case (refactoring with assemblies renaming) can leave application after deployment in unusable state.

So, I would like to deliver with `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=False`, leaving cleanup and actual deployment to MsDeploy.
But, in such scenario, second webapplication cleans up everything, which is not added to it.
Is it possible to override `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=False` on subsequent builds webapplications, if it is `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=False` on first one?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to put 2 applications in the same folder.  If you create a separate .vcproj file for each of your web applications, they will appear as separate nodes in the Solution Explorer; you can then publish them independently by right-clicking on each and selecting Publish.

Comment: This is what we have here and I have to automate it.
It is the way which solutions was built here previously: multiple webapplication per each business goal, all deployed to one IIS website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for such an unlikely happen problem.
In each of additional webapplication, one shall add at the end of csproj/vbproj file following:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer Condition="!$(SkipExtraFilesOnServer)">True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or, if target BeforeBuild is already defined, add to it:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer Condition="!$(SkipExtraFilesOnServer)">True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```